# Remove staff space from MusixTex

Tags: musixtex

My goal is to be able to insert stand alone music notes into text and color them, as it's not possible to do it with `LilyGlyphs` ([cf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627778/insert-colored-music-notes-in-text/627780#627780)), I did it with `MusixTex`, but I've got spacing problems!

In the following MWE there is:

1. "my note" in a tabular, and one with `LilyGlyphs` for comparison
2. "my note" in a `LilyGlyphs` time signature
3. "my notes" in a text. For the first one I achieved to reduce the space before the note with a `hspace{-xx}` hack, and I could probably do the same kind of hack for the space after the note

To remove the upper space, I tried a hack with `vspace{-xx}`, but it did not work.

Also, as I think the space is due to that `MusixTex` keep it for the staff, I tried to remove it with `\setstaffs{1}{0}`, but this way, the note is not printed and the space is not removed, leaving just a large with space!

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\newcommand\myNote[2][]{
  \def\FirstArg{#1}
  \ifx\FirstArg\empty
    % If the first arg is not set, no space moving
  \else
    \hspace{-#1pt}
  \fi
  \scalebox{0.6}{
    \begin{music}
      \instrumentnumber{1}
      \nobarnumbers
      \setclefsymbol{1}\empty
      \setlines{1}{0}
      \nostartrule
      \smallmusicsize
      \startextract
        \notes#2{a}\en
        \setemptybar
      \endextract
    \end{music}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    LilyGlyphs & \quaver\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}\\
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    My note (with MusiXTeX) & \myNote{\cu}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \textcolor{red}{\lilyTimeSignature{6}{\myNote[11]{\cup}}}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nisi
  nisi, eleifend eu dolor vel \myNote[100]{\qu}, hendrerit pretium est. Donec vitae tempor turpis.
  Maecenas ligula arcu, condimentum sit amet feugiat sed, accumsan quis ligula.
  In ac lorem dignissim, venenatis felis ut, maximus magna. Donec vel tortor
  condimentum mi dictum interdum a et tortor\myNote{\wh}. Nam pharetra ullamcorper quam, ut
  pretium elit pellentesque ut. Donec pretium, ipsum at blandit bibendum, odio
  urna tempor dolor, quis tristique orci ante fringilla nisi. Praesent vulputate
  maximus ante, finibus suscipit \myNote{\ccl} massa aliquam sit amet. In nibh nisl, sagittis
  sit amet fermentum quis, interdum eget dolor. Morbi eget varius magna, eu
  tempor nisl. Donec vel urna ultricies, sodales turpis ut, gravida sem. Duis
  consequat laoreet sodales. Curabitur laoreet pretium purus, ut vulputate
  ligula auctor at. Etiam at rhoncus ex. Donec metus ante, ullamcorper vitae
  ultrices a, auctor vel dolor.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit hacky, but I achieved to remove the white spaces.

I used `znotes` instead of `notes` to remove some space after the notes, `\def\afterruleskip{0\elemskip}` to remove some space before the notes, and `hspace` for the rest of the left and right space. For the upper en lower sapce I used a `raisebox` with its `height` and `depth` arguments.

Here is the result. It's not perfect, it has to be tune for each notes.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\newcommand\myNote[1]{%
  \hspace{-092pt}
  \raisebox{-08pt}[6pt][4pt]{%
  \scalebox{0.5}{%
    \begin{music}%
      \instrumentnumber{1}%
      \nobarnumbers%
      \setclefsymbol{1}\empty%
      \setlines{1}{0}%
      \nostartrule%
      \smallmusicsize%
      \def\afterruleskip{0\elemskip}
      \startextract%
        \znotes#1{f}\en%
        \setemptybar%
      \endextract%
    \end{music}%
  }%
  }%
  \hspace{-086pt}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    LilyGlyphs & \quaver\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}\\
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    My note (with MusiXTeX) & \myNote{\cu}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \textcolor{red}{\lilyTimeSignature{6}{\myNote{\cup}}}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nisi
  nisi, eleifend eu dolor vel \myNote{\qu}, hendrerit pretium est. Donec vitae tempor turpis.
  Maecenas ligula arcu, condimentum sit amet feugiat sed, accumsan quis ligula.
  In ac lorem dignissim, venenatis felis ut, maximus magna. Donec vel tortor
  condimentum mi dictum interdum a et tortor\myNote{\wh}. Nam pharetra ullamcorper quam, ut
  pretium elit pellentesque ut. Donec pretium, ipsum at blandit bibendum, odio
  urna tempor dolor, quis tristique orci ante fringilla nisi. Praesent vulputate
  maximus ante, finibus suscipit \myNote{\ccl} massa aliquam sit amet. In nibh nisl, sagittis
  sit amet fermentum quis, interdum eget dolor. Morbi eget varius magna, eu
  tempor nisl. Donec vel urna ultricies, sodales turpis ut \myNote{\hu}, gravida sem. Duis
  consequat laoreet sodales. Curabitur laoreet pretium purus, ut vulputate
  ligula auctor at. Etiam at rhoncus ex. Donec metus ante, ullamcorper vitae
  ultrices a, auctor vel dolor. 
\end{document}
```

[image: Latex notes in text]